How to remove white space between image and shape for visual alignment in LaTeX when using tikz and graphicx?
When I place an image at the top of the page using the page as a reference, there's a white space between the page border and the image. When I then place a rectangle to the left of the image, using the image's top-left corner as a reference, the rectangle is separated from the image by a white space, but there's no white space between the top of the page and the rectangle. As a result, the two items are not visually aligned. I'm not sure whether this white space is added by graphicx or tikz, but I suspect it's graphicx. I want to remove the white margin to align both figures relative to each other.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=216mm,paperheight=280mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=north] (head) at (current page.north)
        {\includegraphics[width=10cm]{head}};
    \draw[black] (head.north east) rectangle ++(3.5,-4.2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Use inner sep=0pt

Actually this is added by tikz. The node has some separation around it, which keeps (for example) a box drawn around the edge from crashing into the contents.
If you add inner sep=0pt to the \node options, you will see it disappear.
See Section 17.2.3 of the PGF/TikZ 3.1.10 manual.
